# Logout all tabs and if you logout in one tab it needs to be logged out automatically in all other tabs

Tags: gmail

We are opening Gmail in two tabs and if you logout in one tab it needs to be logged out automatically in all other tabs

Answer (score 0):

It gets automatically logged out from the other tabs as well if you logout in one tab. If you're NOT getting logged out, try refreshing the page.

Comment: How automatically logout all tabs?